# react-select function call on click event on the chip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Hi I am trying to change a state in my component when there is a click event on a particular chip rendered in the search bar. Is that possible to do?

I am aware of the ***multiValue*** ***multiValueLabel*** and I can for example change the background color of the chip with that, so I thought I could use those tags to change the state but I didn't have any luck.

I have attempted to find a solution with ***isSelected*** tag but I am always reading ***undefined*** in the ***states.isSelected*** when console.logged it.

I feel like I need a `onClick()` functionality somewhere but I can't figure it out. A bit of a guidance would be much appreciated!
I am sharing a live code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-v2-custom-style-forked-zjqik?file=/src/index.js:501-551) so maybe we can discuss over it.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to validate if an option is selected you could use the prop: isOptionSelected

or

```
  const onChange = selectedOptions => setSelected(selectedOptions);
```

with props

```
  isMulti
  value={selected}
  onChange={onChange}
  components={{
    MultiValue: SortableMultiValue,
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach `onClick` listener in `MultiValueLabel` component

```
<Select
  isMulti={true}
  components={{
    MultiValueLabel: (props) => {
      return (
        <div onClick={() => console.log(props.data)}>
          <components.MultiValueLabel {...props} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }}
  {...}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit React Select - Chip OnClick]